# MVC5 Retrieve data with ajax, return json object instead of view

Tags: json, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple function that searches for item I want in my database and retrieves it in my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var user = from m in db.Users select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        user = user.Where(s => s.UserName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

And then in my Javascript I send a value to search:

```
$('#test').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var user = "John";

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Users")",
        data { "searchString": user },
        type: "post",
        success: function (saveResult) {
            console.log(saveResult);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    })
})
```

However of course all this does it return my view inside the console window which is something like:
[image]

But I would like to return a `json` object I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the Json Action method.

```
return Json(user);
```

Edit:

As a side note, I would also set my return Type to be JsonResult for clarity

Comment: Perfect!

Is there a way to change the name of the json object that comes back? It came back as `Array[1]`.

Comment: I'm assuming Array[1] is the content displayed from the console.log(saveResult) call. If so, that's really just the description of what is stored in the saveResult.  Your code is returning an IEnumerable<User> which is serialized to be an Array of objects in JS. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah I get it now, either way it saved me so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just return as JsonResult such as below:

```
 public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
  return Json(new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"});
}
```